# Google Maps API for Business can be used for localhost URL?

Tags: google-maps

I'm working on a new project using geocoding, but now im testing my website locally. How can I register a local URL (ex: `[http://localhost/myWebApp]`)? Or will I see the changes only if my web is on a webhosting service?

Answer (score 0):

By using the javascript V3 api, you can just enter the api key in the script declaration. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=enteryourapikeyhere&sensor=false"></script>
```

You can follow the required steps right here to implement it in your page:

[Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)